# How to update a list in a function in each iteration

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, programming, random

There is a list with numbers 1 to 8 ( `p1` ) and another list (`j`) which contains 4 numbers which shows different 4 positions of the elements in list `p1`. I want to take 4 elements from `p1` related to the 4 numbers of positions from the list `j` and multiply those selected 4 numbers from list `p1` by 2.

The code below is a function that do the procedure that I have mentioned above :

```
p1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

DoMul[p1_] := Module[{nmu, e1, j, mul, Replacement},
j = {1, 6, 7, 8};
i = 1; While[i <= 4,
e1 = Extract[p1, {j[[i]]}];
mul = 2*e1;
Replacement = ReplacePart[p1, j[[i]] -> mul];    
; i++];
Replacement];
```

The problem is that I do not know how to update `p1` in each iteration ( There are 4 iterations ) and the result will be :

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 16}
```

but the correct answer must be :

```
{2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 14, 16}
```

Does anyone know how to update the `p1` list in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
j = {1, 6, 7, 8};

p1[[j]] *= 2;
p1

(* {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 14, 16} *)
```

Replacing your function (I assume you want to keep the argument/original unchanged and return the changed version):

```
p1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

domul[p1_] := Module[{replacement = p1, j = {1, 6, 7, 8}},
   replacement[[j]] *= 2;
   replacement];

domul[p1]

(* {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 14, 16} *)
```

Also note I changed things to lowercase - bad idea in general to use uppercase initials, might clash with *Mathematica* built-in symbols.

Comment: @RunnyKine: LOL - grabbed a coffee, did not see yours. If you'd like this too-similar result deleted, no worries....and a +1 on yours for penance.

Comment: Lol. The more the merrier.

Comment: @ rasher : I used it and  it properly worked out of the function.  But it doesn't work when I use it inside the function `DoMul[p1_]`. Could you please elaborate what the problem is ?!

Comment: @Shellp: see update. Let me know if further clarification needed.

Comment: @ rasher : many thanks for it!!

Answer (score 5):

Just do the following:

```
p1[[j]] = 2 p1[[j]]
```

Then `p1` gives:

```
{2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 14, 16}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redundant way :

```
Fold[MapAt[2 # &, #1, #2] &, p1, j]
```

Comment: @ esprit Thank you esprit!! It's a brilliant way !!

Comment: `MapAt` could also be used `Fold`-lessly here: `MapAt[2 # &, p1, List /@ j]`

Comment: @Aky : Yes, indeed!